# Eclipse extension point for attribute content in JSP editor (webtools)

Tags: eclipse, jsp, eclipse-wtp

I am trying to find extension point for providing custom attribute values in JSP editors, similar to `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.javaCompletionProposalComputer` in JDT.

I looked at WST and JST documentation referenced at http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/documentation/, but found nothing.

Is there such extension point, or some other way to provide custom attribute values for JSP tags? (I want to provide property names for `key` attribute in `fmt:message` tag).

(This is related to my original question about [generic content-assist extension point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1982348/extension-point-for-providing-custom-content-assist-processors-in-eclipse), which seem to not exist)

Answer (score 0):

org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.modelQueryExtensions would be the right way to add the values so that they're offered by content assist and respected during validation.  A completion proposal computer extension is also in the works for WTP 3.2 (part of 2010's Helios release).